# How to create a user class and consult it in my entire project?

Tags: android, kotlin

I'm something new in kotlin, my app has a login section and I want to create a user class after a successful login, I want the class to be consulted in my entire project and I want a single instance of it to be made, how can I do this?

```
data class User(val uid:String, var email:String,var name:String){
   
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the Singleton pattern, which can be implemented in Kotlin as:

```
object User(val uid:String, var email:String,var name:String){
}
```

Then you can use it directly anywhere, e.g. `User.email`.

Reference: https://kotlinlang.org/docs/object-declarations.html#object-declarations